# Скрипт наложения картинки на картинку с добавкой текста

Tags: php

Хотелось бы такой написать. Есть только наложение картинки на картинку.

Answer (score 3):

Давно баловался с генератором юзербаров.

```
$nick = $_GET["name"]; //Получение Ника
$race = "Раса: ".$_GET["race"]; //Получение Расы
$class = "Класс: ".$_GET["class"]; //Получение Класса
$clan = "Клан: ".$_GET["clan"]; //Получение Клана
$lvl = $_GET["lvl"]; //Получение Статуса
$server = "Сервер: ".$_GET["serv"]; //Получение Сервера
$gender = $_GET["gender"]; //Получение Пола
$lvlcount = strlen($lvl); //Определение длины уровня

$im = imageCreateFromPNG('userbar.png'); //открываем рисунок в формате PNG
$avatar=imagecreatefrompng('avatar/'.$race_eng.'_'.$gender.'.png'); //аватар пользователя

$color = ImageColorAllocate($im, 255, 255, 255); //получаем идентификатор цвета RGB

//------------------Рисуем наш текст на картинке(полный путь к шрифту обязателен)------------------
imageTTFText($im, 12, 0, 120, 22, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $nick);
if($lvlcount == 1){ imageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 72, 78, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $lvl); }
if($lvlcount == 2){ imageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 68, 78, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $lvl); }
if($lvlcount == 3){ imageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 64, 78, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $lvl); }
imageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 110, 40, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $race);
imageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 285, 40, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $class);
imageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 110, 65, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $clan);
imageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 285, 65, $color, "/home/localhost/www/userbar/arial.ttf", $server);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

imagecopy($im,$avatar,0,0,0,0,92,89); //Вставляем аватра юзера в наш банер

$imgname = microtime().'_userbar.png'; //Генерируем уникальное название для юзербара

Imagejpeg($im, $imgname, 100); //Сохраняем нашу картинку под качестовм в 100%
imageDestroy($im); //Освобождаем память и закрываем изображение

echo '<img src="'.$imgname.'">'; //Выводим на экран юзербар
```

Comment: надо стороннюю картинку, не аватар. точнее могу сказать так :
что-то типа этого сервиса mag.racked.eu

Comment: ну дак модифицируйте, тут все то же реализовано.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте картинку с текстом (imagefttext,imagepstext,imagettftext), потом выполните ваш скрипт два раза. Ну, или объясните подробнее, что требуется.

1. GD/Imagick?
2. На уровне файлов или на уровне вывода?
3. Шрифт произвольный или заранее заданный?

**Добавлено.**

У Imagic'a есть функция

```
ImagickDraw::annotation //Draws text on the image
```

Не очень удачное название, имхо, но функцию она свою выполняет. Создаете новое изображение нужного размера, пишете на нем текст, потом с нужной прозрачностью накладываете на свой оригинал.

Comment: 1) imagick 2 на уровне вывода 3) шрифт заранее заданный

Comment: У Imagic'a есть функция 

    ImagickDraw::annotation //Draws text on the image  

Не очень удачное название, имхо, но функию она свою выполняет.  
Создаете новое изображение нужного размера, пишете на нем текст, потом с нужной прозрачностью накладываете на свой оригинал.